# Error updating python-cryptography from terminal 16.04

Tags: command-line, package-management

I am trying to update and upgrade the packages in Ubuntu 16.04.

I got this:

```
dpkg: error processing package python-cryptography (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-cryptography
```

I tried: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall dpkg`

I got this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 python-cryptography : Depends: python-asn1crypto but it is not going to be inst         alled
                       Depends: python-idna (>= 2.1) but 2.0-3 is to be installe         d
                       Breaks: python-openssl (< 16.0.0) but 0.15.1-2build1 is t         o be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a s         olution).
```

Someone give a hand?

Comment: Run `sudo apt -f install`.

Answer (score 2):

The package having issues is ***python-cryptography*** , NOT dpkg. dpkg is fine.

Try doing:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

If that fails, then try:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Comment: sudo apt-get -f install

i got:

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: sudo dpkg --configur -a



dpkg: error processing package python-cryptography (--configure):
 package is in a very bad inconsistent state; you should
 reinstall it before attempting configuration
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-cryptography

Comment: @AnandArun are you sure you put sudo before? Otherwise it seems that one apt/dpkg command is still running. Only one program dpkg/apt/synaptic, etc can access the dpkg database, so running two commands simultaneously will give that error (13: Permission denied). Try rebooting and issuing the command again. Or try killing/closing any other program accessing database.

Comment: Thanks!! It worked! I restarted the terminal and now i may continue updating, upgrading. Thanks a lot!